# Regex for car number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, validation

Good afternoon, I need a mask so that the user can enter at the beginning: 1 - letter, 3 - digits in a row, 2 letters, a space, 2 or 3 digits. Type A111AA 777 or C111TY 45 format. I get false all the time with any letter :

```
    const [carNumber, setCarNumber] = useState('') 
<input
                                            type="text"
                                            name="name"
                                            placeholder="A001AA 01"
                                            required
                                            value={carNumber}
                                            onChange={event => {
                                      
                                                const value = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
                                                console.log(value)
                                            
                                                const regex = /^[АВЕКМНОРСТУХABEKMHOPCTYX]?\d{0,3}[АВЕКМНОРСТУХABEKMHOPCTYX]?\s?\d{2,3}$/ui;
                                                const answer = regex.test(value)
                                                console.log(answer)
                                         
                                                if (regex.test(value) || value === '') {
                                                    setCarNumber(value);
                                                }
                                            }}
                                        />
```

I wrote it correctly, but I don't get anything in input.What could be the error?

Comment: "2 letters" but `[АВЕКМНОРСТУХABEKMHOPCTYX]?` - don't you mean `[АВЕКМНОРСТУХABEKMHOPCTYX]{2}` ?

Comment: also "3 - digits in a row" but your regex says "at least 0 digits, at most 3 digits in a row". so what is it? :P

Comment: `^[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]{2}\s\d{2,3}$` try this maybe?

Comment: Correct, you cannot input anything since you added the regex check on the change, and thus you need to make sure even partial matches pass the validation. I think the only pattern you can use in this code is `/^[АВЕКМНОРСТУХABEKMHOPCTYX](?:\d{1,3}(?:[АВЕКМНОРСТУХABEKMHOPCTYX]{1,2} ?\d{0,3})?)?$/i`